# Distorted background image on HTC Desire

Tags: background-image, aspect-ratio, android

I designed an app for htc desire. The background image used for the app looks good in Eclipse layout, when installed in phone it is stretched.

Comment: Can you let us know as in what emulator mode are you testing. HTC Desire is a WVGA device and if you test on an emulator which is HVGA then you might get this difference.

Answer (score 0):

Nine patch your image as HTC Desire is an WVGA device..

You need to get in the habit of nine patching your images..

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the support-screens option in your AndroidManifest.xml. If you don't, the system will assume your application is coded for a medium-sized screen and will stretch the images you put in drawable-hdpi.